# If I have an original audio frame in Android, how to encode it using AMR or AAC?

Tags: android, frame, encoder, amr

If I have an original audio frame in Android, how to encode it using AMR AAC, or any other encoder?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
// Specify the audio and video encoding
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

[developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioEncoder%28int%29)

Comment: Not exactly that way. What I want is to encode a pure audio frame piled in an array like "byte in[]" and encode it into "byte[]out" .